# Extract specific union item given generic param in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Given an union of typescript objects, I want to extract a specific union item.
This will help me to dynamically type a function where a specific `id` is passed as params.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAgjAvDA3sGMCWATAXDAcgEMCAadGAZyiICcBjAC3zQwyPwDsBXAWwCMotCgF9gY0JFgAhJKgo58BfmQrU6TFhQz98lELUycA5qPHBJ0GAFkwAVU6YA9pzkIAPjGkXwVgOJQIABitE68Ds6cADwAKjBQAB4gUJzYlDb2ji4A2gQ4BAC6AHxythE5ediF8UkpaTBxAPwZ5a5cUABuQhYA9ABUfeh9MACSNdD0IDC%20sADC007xAI7cRAA26SCMsABmTmtrTgDuRsa4QzAXMzDzyKzDGIqEKuQwD1Q0DMzyb2wwulQDKcLhgxL8wX0epY5nIAsFQuEstFlAQihYgA)

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
type A = {
  id: 'a',
  search: {
    a: number
  }
}

type B = {
  id: 'b',
  search: {
    b: string
  }
}

type MyUnion = A | B

type GetFromUnion<T extends MyUnion['id']> = // complete the implementation

/**
 * I expect type C to be equal to:
 * 
 * type C = {
 *   id: 'b',
 *   search: {
 *    b: string
 *   }
 * }
 */
type C = GetFromUnion<'b'>
```

What I tried, but doesn't work:

```
// Always return never
type GetFromUnion<T extends MyUnion['id']> = MyUnion['id'] extends T ? MyUnion : never
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to the rescue:

```
type GetFromUnion<T extends MyUnion['id']> = Extract<MyUnion, {id : T}>
```

The implementation of `Extract` is:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```